# UITextview: how to indent the text?

Tags: objective-c

Ok i'm trying to create a ruled notebook view.

The code to create this is below

```
@interface QuickNoteNoteTextView ()
    @property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
    @property (nonatomic) CGPoint endPoint;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *lineColor;
@end

@implementation QuickNoteNoteTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     // Drawing code
     // Get the graphics context
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     [super drawRect:rect];

     // Get the height of a single text line
     NSString *alpha = @"ABCD";
     CGSize textSize = [alpha sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:self.contentSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];
     NSUInteger height = textSize.height;

     // Get the height of the view or contents of the view whichever is bigger
     textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:self.contentSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping ];
     NSUInteger contentHeight = (rect.size.height > textSize.height) ? (NSUInteger)rect.size.height : textSize.height;

     NSUInteger offset = 6 + height; // MAGIC Number 6 to offset from 0 to get first line OK ???
     contentHeight += offset;
     // Draw ruled lines
     CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, 1);
     for(int i=offset;i < contentHeight;i+=height) {
         CGPoint lpoints[2] = { CGPointMake(0, i), CGPointMake(rect.size.width, i) };
         CGContextStrokeLineSegments(ctx, lpoints, 2);
     }

     //vertical line
     self.startPoint = CGPointMake(22.0, self.frame.size.height * -1);
     self.endPoint = CGPointMake(22.0, self.frame.size.height * 2);
     self.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];


     CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, NO);

     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [self.lineColor CGColor]);

     CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);

     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.endPoint.x, self.endPoint.y);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.startPoint.x + 2.0f, self.startPoint.y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.endPoint.x + 2.0f, self.endPoint.y);

     CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);


 }
```

This code correctly draws horizontal ruled lines in a UITextview and a vertical margin line on the left.

The last thing i'm trying to do is shift the text in my textview right so that it sits to the right of the vertical line.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why not move it by twenty pixels to the right?

Comment: Because then you get a 20 pixel gap on the left as the horizontal lines have shifted by 20 pixels

Comment: solution: make the background and the text view two separate views.

Comment: And textView must be Transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem by using contentInset to push the text to the right by 20 pixels, then amended my drawRect to extend the horizontal line by -20 to account for the contentInset